# Javascript Generated Image Gallery

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a dynamic image gallery from JSON files using JS. The final intent is to move through the nested objects in JSON, grab the image source locations and add them to a list to be displayed within a single picture box (each animal has its own box, but multiple pictures are displayed/scrolled automatically per box). The animal name and description are obtained as well, as a figure caption shown as an overlay for each picturebox.

An example of the simplified javascript (which I know will display multiple pictures per animal in a gallery, but I just want to test this in stages for understanding):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function displayPhotos(data) {
  var photoHTML = "";
  $.each(petfinder.pets,function(i,pet) {
      $.each(pet.media.photos,function(i, photo){
        photoHTML += '<div class="picbox"><figure><img src="' + photo.$t + '" class="frame"><figcaption>' + pet.description + '</figcaption></figure></div>';
      });
  }); // end each

  $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
};

$.getJSON("paws.json", displayPhotos);

});
```

The JSON data is as follows:

```
{
  "@encoding": "iso-8859-1",
  "@version": "1.0",
  "petfinder": {
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "lastOffset": {
      "$t": "25"
    },
    "pets": {
      "pet": [
        {
          "options": {
            "option": [
              {
                "$t": "altered"
              },
              {
                "$t": "hasShots"
              },
              {
                "$t": "noDogs"
              },
              {
                "$t": "noCats"
              }
            ]
          },
          "status": {
            "$t": "A"
          },
          "contact": {
            "phone": {
              "$t": "(618) 833-3647"
            },
            "state": {
              "$t": "IL"
            },
            "address2": {
              "$t": "N/A"
            },
            "email": {
              "$t": "pawsplace1@yahoo.com"
            },
            "city": {
              "$t": "Anna"
            },
            "zip": {
              "$t": "62906"
            },
            "fax": {
              "$t": "N/A"
            },
            "address1": {
              "$t": "139 East Vienna Street"
            }
          },
          "age": {
            "$t": "Adult"
          },
          "size": {
            "$t": "L"
          },
          "media": {
            "photos": {
              "photo": [
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/1/?bust=1371662519&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/1/?bust=1371662519&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/1/?bust=1371662519&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/1/?bust=1371662519&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/1/?bust=1371662519&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/2/?bust=1371662521&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/2/?bust=1371662521&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/2/?bust=1371662521&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/2/?bust=1371662521&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/2/?bust=1371662521&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/3/?bust=1371662522&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/3/?bust=1371662522&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/3/?bust=1371662522&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/3/?bust=1371662522&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26443178/3/?bust=1371662522&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "$t": "26443178"
          },
          "shelterPetId": {
            "$t": "1"
          },
          "breeds": {
            "breed": [
              {
                "$t": "Labrador Retriever"
              },
              {
                "$t": "Pit Bull Terrier"
              }
            ]
          },
          "name": {
            "$t": "MIKEY"
          },
          "sex": {
            "$t": "M"
          },
          "description": {
            "$t": "Mikey is a Lab/Pit Bull mix who was born in August of 2011,  He was adopted from PAWS after he had been found abandoned out in the middle of nowhere.  The family had him for about a year, and then they got a couple more dogs.  That didn't work out because Mikey prefers to be an only child (dog).  He does well with people, he just prefers not to share them.  He loves to cuddle, wants to be a lap dog, and he will smile for you.   He's a beautiful boy, and he has been neutered, micro-chipped, dewormed, has been tested for heartworms, is current on his routine vacinations and is on a heartworm preventative.  The adoption fee for him is $200.\n"
          },
          "mix": {
            "$t": "yes"
          },
          "shelterId": {
            "$t": "IL09"
          },
          "lastUpdate": {
            "$t": "2013-06-19T17:21:59Z"
          },
          "animal": {
            "$t": "Dog"
          }
        },
        {
          "options": {
            "option": [
              {
                "$t": "altered"
              },
              {
                "$t": "hasShots"
              },
              {
                "$t": "housetrained"
              }
            ]
          },
          "status": {
            "$t": "A"
          },
          "contact": {
            "phone": {
              "$t": "(618) 833-3647"
            },
            "state": {
              "$t": "IL"
            },
            "address2": {
              "$t": "N/A"
            },
            "email": {
              "$t": "pawsplace1@yahoo.com"
            },
            "city": {
              "$t": "Anna"
            },
            "zip": {
              "$t": "62906"
            },
            "fax": {
              "$t": "N/A"
            },
            "address1": {
              "$t": "139 East Vienna Street"
            }
          },
          "age": {
            "$t": "Adult"
          },
          "size": {
            "$t": "M"
          },
          "media": {
            "photos": {
              "photo": [
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/1/?bust=1476815920&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/1/?bust=1476815920&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/1/?bust=1476815920&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/1/?bust=1476815920&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/1/?bust=1476815920&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/2/?bust=1476815921&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/2/?bust=1476815921&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/2/?bust=1476815921&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/2/?bust=1476815921&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/2/?bust=1476815921&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/3/?bust=1476815922&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/3/?bust=1476815922&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/3/?bust=1476815922&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/3/?bust=1476815922&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/26605681/3/?bust=1476815922&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "$t": "26605681"
          },
          "shelterPetId": {
            "$t": "2"
          },
          "breeds": {
            "breed": {
              "$t": "Domestic Short Hair"
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "$t": "DELILAH"
          },
          "sex": {
            "$t": "F"
          },
          "description": {
            "$t": "Delilah is a beautiful gray tortoiseshell female who was  born around  the middle of March, 2013.; She and her brother and sisters were owner surrendered because their family didn't have their mom spayed; she had kittens; and they didn't want the kittens.; Delilah is just a gorgeous, dignified lovely lady who would like nothing more than to spend hours on your lap just purring and keeping you company!  Come get her and give her that chance today!  We guarantee you will never regret it!"
          },
          "mix": {
            "$t": "yes"
          },
          "shelterId": {
            "$t": "IL09"
          },
          "lastUpdate": {
            "$t": "2013-07-07T12:24:24Z"
          },
          "animal": {
            "$t": "Cat"
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: **@airsoftsoldrecn9**, the `paws.json` is not in correct form. Please use the JSON available at https://gist.github.com/hygull/aeb34b1d8808c440117f0a4f8e960e62. I have corrected it. You can also check the validity of your JSON at https://jsoneditoronline.org.

Comment: Change **petfinder.pets** to data.`petfinder.pets.pet` and **pet.media.photos** to `pet.media.photos.photo`. It will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specified JSON was not in valid form as it is missing two `}` (curley braces) and one `]` (right big bracket). I visited https://jsoneditoronline.org and corrected it.

> **Note:** I have saved the corrected JSON file `paws.json` at [this web page](https://gist.github.com/hygull/aeb34b1d8808c440117f0a4f8e960e62) on Github.
>   Please use that one.

The error line is highlighted in the below image (on left). I have added `]}}` to fix the issue with JSON.

[image]

Finally, try the below HTML code on your server.

> **Note:** I am Django developer so I used Django (Python's web framework) to serve the web page. It worked fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Read JSON and process</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Populate all the photos and descriptions here-->
<div id='photos'>
</div>

<!-- Code to grab pets/photos and creating div elements -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("paws.json' %}", function(data){
      // console.log("It's great to see you here.");
      // console.log(data);
      var photoHTML = ''

      // Storing pets to a variable named pets
      var pets = data.petfinder.pets.pet; // Here pets(in paws.json) has 2 items

      // Loop through pets array
      $.each(pets, function(index, pet){
          // console.log("PETS INDEX :", index);
          // Storing photos to a varibale named photos
          var photos = pet.media.photos.photo;
          // Loop through photos array
          $.each(photos, function(index, photo){
              // console.log("PHOTO INDEX ", index);
              // console.log(photo.$t)
              photoHTML += '<div class="picbox"><figure><img src="' + photo.$t + '" class="frame"><figcaption>' + pet.description.$t + '</figcaption></figure></div>';
          })
      })
      console.log(photoHTML)
      $('#photos').html(photoHTML);
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

That's it.

Comment: You're welcome. This excellent question landed me on the track where I learnt the use of jQuery's **$.getJSON()**.

Comment: I applied your solution, but I seem to be doing something very wrong. Would you mind taking a look at the URL below? I would be curious to know what I am missing: http://paws.freedynamicdns.org/paws_gallery/

Comment: Check if you have the **paws.json** file in the same directory where the html code resides. As in my case, I have **index.html** and **paws.json** in the same directory. You can check it at https://hygull.github.io/paws.html and source is available at https://github.com/hygull/hygull.github.io. I have also checked your github repository, it does not have the working code. I will suggest you to copy code from my repository to try. Please comment if you face any problem.

Comment: Now I got, you do not have **paws.json** file inside **paws_gallery** folder of your website. It is the root cause of  problem.

Comment: Actually I just grabbed the concept from that github project, so it isn't mine. My JSON file had some delimiting errors still, which I cleared up (including the comments which petfinder includes as part of the request). I have quite a bit of duplicate information and a few other things to work out, but at least I can parse the json file and throw out image data right now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Okay, it's great message. You fixed the problem related to this web scrapping work. Great job.